# How to change the picture without affect anything?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

For example, i have a sub site with 4 pictures. So when i click on one picture, it will go into another sub site. But now i want to change the picture without affect another sub site. Which means that after i change the picture, and click on it, it still can go into another sub site. So how to change the picture without affect anything?

I attached a picture to give a clear explanation. I click on edit page > click on the picture that i want to change > then it comes out a window ( look at the picture that given. If I am not wrong, is it just change the link only that under " Image URL "?

Maybe you will ask why not i just try to paste the link on it, but I cannot touch anything before i get the right answer. Please help me, thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you mean, you have a site with multiple image links; you want to change the image without it affecting the link to the sub-site?

Changing the image to some other image doesn't affect the link itself.

Comment: Yes. So as in above the picture, i can just change the image URL  then can change to another image  already right? Or is there any others way except this method?

Comment: i presume your creating the links on the page? there can be many ways to update the links on a page depending on requirements. If you just want to change the image then this way would be the simplest way. so you have 4 images but want to change one image without effecting the other 3? if so the way you have shown is the simplest and straight forward without having to code and will not effect the others (image and url links)

Comment: Nope, i will upload new image and a new link then paste on in to replace the old link. So when i click ok, it will change into the new image without affect those other three images and another subsites. This is only way that i found and may can use in my share point.